# Laravel Validation: Custom message as array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I'm trying to validate a regular email/password login with some basic rules:

```
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => ['bail', 'required', 'string', 'email', 'exists:users.users,email'],
            'password' => ['bail', 'required', 'string', 'password'],
        ], [
            'email.exists' => "Email does not exist in our system"
        ]);
    }
```

When displaying these errors, it's easy enough to output them below my input:

[image]
However, where the "Invalid Email" text is shown within the top right of the input, I'm trying to make that custom, and not a hardcoded string in my component. Ideally, this would also come from the error message - though I have no idea how to approach doing so. In my mind, it would look something like this, but I'm struggling to figure out how to make the Validator accept an array rather than a string. Is this possible?

```
'email.exists' => ["Invalid email",
                   "Email does not exist in our system"
                   ]
```

Comment: As far as I know, you can't use an array as the message for a given rule. What's the code that's used to generate/display the text "Invalid Email"? I've never seen that in any of the validation I've done with Laravel; is it custom?

Comment: Do you know about request?

Comment: @TimLewis it's just a custom input Vue component I'm creating. I sort of think of it as a "title", with the main message being the description. Ultimately the errors are just an array as props on that input component.

Comment: Where is the frontend code?

Comment: Ah sorry, I misread; I see now that you said "It's a hard-coded string". And yeah, I know that all error messages are arrays (which is why `$errors->first('email')` would return what it does, but it's because `email.exists` is separate from `email.required`, etc etc; each of those only has a single message. It _might_ be possible to get `$errors->first('email')[0]` to work, but I'm not sure, since there's a lot that happens behind the scenes with the `Validator` class.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I don't really consider the front end code a factor here, as it's ultimately just consuming the array of errors that gets returned from your standard validation in Laravel.

Comment: @iamnull90 please check my answer hope it works for you if you understand the code

Comment: I guess then you just need to add `'email.email ' => 'Invalid Email'` in your array. Each validation has its own error message

Comment: Another thought that's hacky and gross, is passing a string like `Invalid Email|The Email Field is Invalid`, then splitting it in your component (`explode('|', $errors-first('email'))`), but that just feels wrong :P

Comment: @TimLewis Oh I like that! That might be my best bet here. I'm not sure going for elegant is worth the trouble or even possible at this point. Thanks man!

Comment: Anytime :) It's dirty and I felt gross typing it, but it _should_ work for your use case. Just be aware that if you don't pass a string that has a `|` in it, you won't be able to access `[1]` (the "2nd part" of the error message), as it won't exist. It would still be interesting to see if you can refactor the validator to accept an array of messages for any given rule, but who knows how much of a rabbit-hole that would be. Cheers!